# Draw image from pixel array on canvas with putImageData

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, pixel, putimagedata

I am working on a project that can encrypt an image and redraw the decrypted image on canvas. As I am still pretty new to coding and programming, I am currently having issues redrawing the decrypted image data, which is a pixel array in the form R,G,B,A. I thought this would be possible by simply putting the data into

```
ctx.putImageData(imgd,0,0);
```

But firebug tells me that the value does not implement the interface for imagedata. I have posted the entire array [here](http://pastebin.com/KDZrXzbU). The image is 160px wide and 120px high.

Is there any way to reformat the array so that it is drawable on the canvas?

Comment: Bart - it's just the variable i assigned to the array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming `imgd` is simply an Array containing all byte values, you still need to convert the array to ImageData.

```
var imgd = [27,32,26,28,33,27,30,35,29,31.....]

// first, create a new ImageData to contain our pixels
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(160, 120); // width x height
var data = imgData.data;

// copy img byte-per-byte into our ImageData
for (var i = 0, len = 160 * 120 * 4; i < len; i++) {
    data[i] = imgd[i];
}

// now we can draw our imagedata onto the canvas
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: `var imgData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(imgd), 160, 120)`?

Comment: That's a relatively recent addition to the spec. It's an experimental API and not supported in IE.

Answer (score 18):

Using Uint8 you can this much quicker:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = [27,32,26,28, ... ];

// Get a pointer to the current location in the image.
var palette = ctx.getImageData(0,0,160,120); //x,y,w,h
// Wrap your array as a Uint8ClampedArray
palette.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(img)); // assuming values 0..255, RGBA, pre-mult.
// Repost the data.
ctx.putImageData(palette,0,0);
```

No need to go byte-by-byte unless you need to modify the values first.

Comment: `var palette = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(img), 160, 120)`?

Comment: "palette".. hmm, that sounds like something else. I would probably call the variable "imageData" or something more helpful.